# XSLT for .NET CF?

Tags: .net, xslt, compact-framework, coldfusion

Is there any XSLT library available for the Windows Mobile platform? I need to transform my XML document to HTML. It can be a plus if compatible with .NET CF.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: hi, what exactly is your platform? I could not find it in .NET CF 3.5 for WM5 Pocket PC. The only thing I could find in System.Xml.Xsl is an exception

Comment: hi Ben, you are right: i completely missed that no mobile platform actually supports System.Xml.Xsl. I updated my answer with a new suggestion which might be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The [XslCompiledTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx) should be supported in the .NET CF.</strike>

**EDIT**

Apparently *XslCompiledTransform* is not supported on any mobile platform for the .NET CF.

Maybe [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) and related classes are suitable for your needs. They are supported in **.NET CF 3.5** on Windows CE, Windows Mobile for Smartphone, Windows Mobile for Pocket PC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see blog post from August 2006. [OpenNETCF](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ayakhnin/CategoryView,category,OpenNETCF.aspx).